# How to put FTP file into a certain map

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

```py
remotefile=f'{fileName}'
with open(remotefile, "rb") as file:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % remotefile, file)
```

How to put the file into a certain map?

Comment: What is *"map"*? Do you mean *"directory"*?

Comment: what is `map`? if you mean `directory`/`folder` then you should use `remotefile = f'{folder}/{fileName}'` (and `folder` means even nested folders like `"folder1/folder2"` but they have to exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to put in folder/directory then you can do one of two things

1. change remote folder before `STOR`

```
localfile  = 'test/input.txt'

remotefile = 'output.txt'

ftp.cwd('folder1/folder2')  # go to some folder

with open(localfile, 'rb') as file_handler:
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {remotefile}', file_handler)
```

2. use remote folder in `remotefile`

```
localfile  = 'test/input.txt'

remotefile = 'folder1/folder2/output.txt'

with open(localfile, 'rb') as file_handler:
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {remotefile}', file_handler)
```

---

In both situations folder has to exists. If it doesn't exist then you have to create it.

And first you has to create `folder1` and later `folder2`, etc.

```
ftp.mkd('folder1')
ftp.mkd('folder1/folder2')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full code which I used for tests

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect('0.0.0.0', 2121)  # pyftpdlib as default runs on port 2121
ftp.login()

# --- test 0 (create nested folders) ---

ftp.mkd('folder1')
ftp.mkd('folder1/folder2')

# --- test 1 ---

localfile  = 'test/input.txt'
remotefile = 'folder1/folder2/output1.txt'

with open(localfile, 'rb') as file_handler:
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {remotefile}', file_handler)

# --- test 2 ---

localfile  = 'test/input.txt'
remotefile = 'output2.txt'

ftp.cwd('folder1/folder2')

with open(localfile, 'rb') as file_handler:
    ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {remotefile}', file_handler)
```

I tested it on local FTP server using python module [pyftpdlib](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib/)

```
# install module

python -m pip install pyftpdlib

# run FTP server (with "write mode" for anonymous users)

python -m pyftpdlib --write
```

This server runs on port `2121` instead of standard `21`